# Irreducibility of $X^6+X^3+1$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Could anyone advise me on how to prove $X^6+X^3+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X] \ ?$

I'm thinking of substituting $X=Y+1$ into the equation, do some tedious computations to simplify and use Eisenstein's criterion. May I know if that is the correct approach?

Thank you.

Comment: What "tedious" computations? Not terrible at all. Computing a $\;4\times 4\;$ matrix's determinant: that's tedious and boring!

Answer (score 3):

$$(x+1)^6+(x+1)^3+1=x^6+6x^5+15x^4+21x^3+18x^2+9x+3$$

Well, Eisenstein is now a piece of cake, uh?

Comment: but is there any thumb of rule that says what $x+a$ i should substitute in this kind of problems?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't, @PraphullaKoushik, yet in this case the substitution looked promising by seeing the free coefficient: we'd get $\;1+1+1=3\;$ a , prime.

Comment: +100 for "in this case the substitution looked promising by seeing the free coefficient: we'd get $1+1+1=3$, a prime" This does makes lot of sense

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Work out the discriminant of the polynomial, then the primes $p$ dividing this discriminant are the only possible ones we could hope to apply Eisenstein at $p$ to. For example, for $X^6+X^3+1$ has discriminant equal to $-3^9$ so the only hope to apply Eisenstein is with $p=3.$ To see what linear shift to apply, write the polynomial as a perfect power mod $p.$ Here the polynomial is $X^6 - 2X^3 +1 = (X^3-1)^2 = (X-1)^6$ mod $3,$ so you want to apply $x\mapsto x+1.$ The reason behind this is related to ramification theory.

Comment: What’s going on is that the given polynomial is the ninth cyclotomic polynomial, whose roots are $3$-adically close to $1$. So by shifting the roots by $1$, you get roots close to zero, good for Eisenstein.

Comment: @RagibZaman : That concept is really out of my coverage area :P I think i need some more time to get it.... Thank you for sparing your time for me :)

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thank you. But how do I find a prime element $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $p$ divides all the coeficients but $p$ does not divide $1$ and $p^2$ does not divide $3$ in $\mathbb{Q} \ ?$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo,. I don't understand your question: you mean in general or in **this** particular case?

Comment: To use Eisenstein's criterion to prove $$(x+1)^6+(x+1)^3+1=x^6+6x^5+15x^4+21x^3+18x^2+9x+3$$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X],$ I need to find prime $p \in  \mathbb{Q}$ such that $p$ divides the product of all the coefficients, $p^2$ does not divide $3$ and $p$ does not divide $1$ in $\mathbb{Q}.$ But how is this possible?

Comment: Er...@AlexyVincenzo, are you telling me that you can't find a prime number that divides $\;3,9,18,21,15,6\;$ but s.t. its square doesn't divide $\;3\;$ ??

Comment: And it is **not** in $\;\Bbb Q\;$ but in $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , of course (why?  Think of Gauss Lemma)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do the multiplication, write $X^9-1=(X^6+X^3+1)\cdot(X^3-1)$. Now use your $X=Y+1$ trick and reduce mod 3:
$$\begin{align}
(Y+1)^9-1&=\left((Y+1)^6+(Y+1)^3+1\right)\cdot((Y+1)^3-1)\\
Y^9+1^9-1&=\left((Y+1)^6+(Y+1)^3+1\right)\cdot(Y^3+1^3-1)\\
Y^9&=\left((Y+1)^6+(Y+1)^3+1\right)\cdot Y^3\\
Y^6&=(Y+1)^6+(Y+1)^3+1\\
\end{align}$$
which tells you that all terms besides $Y^6$ have coefficient divisible by 3 (note that the Frobenius automorphism was used for the second line). Now plug $X=1$ into your original to find that the constant term is exactly three and then Eisenstein is good to go. The upshot to this method is that it generalizes to when you need to show, say, that $X^{78}+X^{75}+\cdots + X^3+1$ is irreducible.